$3k+1$ prime divisors of $n^3+3$
Prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers $p\equiv1\pmod3$ such that there is no integer $x$ such that $p\mid (x^3+3)$.
We know that $P(x)=x^3+3$ is irreducible in $Q[x] $; thus, the density of its prime divisors is $1/3$. on the other hand $x^3$ produces all remaiders modulo any $3k+2$ prime number. so if there were finitely many such $3k+1$ prime numbers, the density of its prime divisors would be $1$.
But I want an elementary solution!

I have doubts whether the presented proof is rigorous.

cubic reciprocity leads to a proof, but I don't know that I'd call that elementary.    And see this duplicate for the polynomial $x^3-2$.

Well, all primes $p$   that can be expressed as
$$ p= 7 x^2 + 3xy + 9 y^2  $$
have no cube root of $3.$
The primes
$$   r = u^2 + uv + 61 v^2  $$  do have a cube root of $3.$
Theorem of Jacobi. Cox gives this as an exercise in his Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2.$  In the first(1989) edition this is exercise 4.15 on pages 90 and 91.  He compares this to Theorem 4.15 on page 80, which does the cube root of $2.$   Oh, Cox uses the equivalent version $4p = s^2 + 243 t^2$
Ireland and Rosen also make this an exercise, second edition (1990), it is exercise 23 on page 135.  They also write this as $4p = C^2 + 243 B^2$  for there to be cube roots of $3$
Why not: Theorem 9.12 in Cox is:

Theorem 9.12  Let $ax^2 + bxy + c y^2$ be a primitive positive definite quadratic form of discriminant $D < 0,$ and let $S$  be the
set of primes represented by $ax^2 + bxy + c y^2.$  Then the Dirichlet
density $\delta(S) $  exists and is given by the formulas
$\delta(S) = \frac{1}{2h(D)}  $    if  $ax^2 + bxy + c y^2$  is
properly equivalent to its opposite; otherwise $\delta(S) =
> \frac{1}{h(D)}  $
In particular, $ax^2 + bxy + c y^2$  represents infinitely many prime
numbers.

In particular, $h(-243) = 3,$  the principal form is $x^2 + xy + 61 y^2$  and is equivalent to its opposite, so the principal form represents $1/6$  of primes. The other two classes are $7 x^2 + 3xy + 9 y^2$  and $7 x^2 - 3xy + 9 y^2.$  These are opposites and not equivalent, but they represent the same primes, that being $1/3$  of all primes.
